# Namespace Syntax "::Foo"

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces

What does this syntax mean when there is no namespace attached in front of the double colons "::" ?

Suppose I have a class Foo. And somewhere in the code there is something like ::Foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It denotes the global namespace.

Consider this code for example

```
#include <iostream>

int x = 10;

namespace N
{
    int x = 20; // Or you could write int x = 10 + ::x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 30;

    std::cout << ::x + N::x + x << std::endl;
}
```

Take into account that in this statement

```
    std::cout << ::x + N::x + x << std::endl;
```

you could write `::N::x` instead of `N::x` because namespace N is enclosed in the global namespace.

Comment: If i declare using namespace std; at the very top,
can I write ::cout << ....... << ::endl; instead?

Comment: @cpp_noname Yes, you may. You should read about qualified name lookup